# How to Upload Mutiple images to an API in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

In my application user should be able to upload mutiple images on server (more than 8 images at a time)? I am able to upload one image at a time but i am not able to upload mutiple images at a time? please suggest me how to do it, it would be helpfull for me? thank you.
Here is my code:

```
final List<File> _image = [];
final picker = ImagePicker();

final pickedFile = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera,imageQuality: 100);
                   if(pickedFile != null){
                     File? croppedFile = await ImageCropper.cropImage(sourcePath: pickedFile.path,
                     aspectRatioPresets: [
                       CropAspectRatioPreset.square,
                       CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio3x2,
                       CropAspectRatioPreset.original,
                       CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio4x3,
                       CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio16x9
                     ],
                       androidUiSettings: const AndroidUiSettings(
                         toolbarTitle: 'Cropper',
                         toolbarColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                         toolbarWidgetColor: Colors.white,
                         activeControlsWidgetColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                         initAspectRatio: CropAspectRatioPreset.original,
                         lockAspectRatio: false,
                       ),
                         iosUiSettings: const IOSUiSettings(
                           minimumAspectRatio: 1.0,
                         )
                     );
                     if(croppedFile != null){
                       setState(() {
                         // _scanQrCode = croppedFile.path;
                         imageFile = croppedFile.path;
                         imageFile = _scanQrCode;
                         print(imageFile);
                         _image.add(File(croppedFile.path));
                       });
                     }
                   }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use, [flutter_uploader](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_uploader):

Import package:

```
import 'package:flutter_uploader/flutter_uploader.dart';
```

Initialize uploader:
This is a singleton object

```
final uploader = FlutterUploader();
```

Create new upload task:

```
final taskId = await uploader.enqueue(
  url: "your upload link", //required: url to upload to
  files: [FileItem(filename: filename, savedDir: savedDir, fieldname:"file")], // required: list of files that you want to upload
  method: UploadMethod.POST, // HTTP method  (POST or PUT or PATCH)
  headers: {"apikey": "api_123456", "userkey": "userkey_123456"},
  data: {"name": "john"}, // any data you want to send in upload request
  showNotification: false, // send local notification (android only) for upload status
  tag: "upload 1"); // unique tag for upload task
);
```

listen for upload progress

```
  final subscription = uploader.progress.listen((progress) {
      //... code to handle progress
  });
```

listen for upload result

```
  final subscription = uploader.result.listen((result) {
      //... code to handle result
  }, onError: (ex, stacktrace) {
      // ... code to handle error
  });
```

note: when tasks are cancelled, it will send on onError handler as exception with status = cancelled

Cancel an upload task:

```
uploader.cancel(taskId: taskId);
```

Cancel all upload tasks:

```
uploader.cancelAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Dio package for single/multiple/dynamic number of image upload.

package

```
dio: ^4.0.0
image_picker: ^0.8.3+3
```

import package

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart' as Dio;
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
```

For a known number of images(Ex: 2 images)

```
XFile? pickedFile1;
XFile? pickedFile2;

void selectImage1(ImageSource imageSource) async {
    try {
      pickedFile1 = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: imageSource);
    } finally {
    }
  }

 void selectImage2(ImageSource imageSource) async {
    try {
      pickedFile2 = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: imageSource);
    } finally {
    }
  }

  void create() async {
    try {
        if (pickedFile1 != null) {
          Dio.FormData formData = new Dio.FormData.fromMap({
            "name": name.text,
            "year": year.text,
            "image_1": await Dio.MultipartFile.fromFile(pickedFile1!.path,
                filename: pickedFile1!.path.split('/').last),
            "image_2": await Dio.MultipartFile.fromFile(pickedFile2!.path,
                filename: pickedFile2!.path.split('/').last)
          });
          await VehicleServices.create(formData);
        } else {}
    } catch (e) {} finally {
    }
  }
```

VehicleServices class

```
static Future<bool> create(FormData data) async {
    try {
      Response response =
      await Dio().post(
        "$baseURL/vehicles",
        data: data,
      );
      if(response.statusCode==201){
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    } catch(e){
      return false;
    }
  }
```

For dynamic numbers of images(Ex: 0,1,2,3)

```
List<XFile> pickedFile = [];

void selectImage() async {
    try {
      pickedFile = (await ImagePicker().pickMultiImage())!;
    } finally {
    }
 }

  void create() async {
    try {
        var arr = [];
        for (var img in pickedFile) {
          arr.add(await Dio.MultipartFile.fromFile(img.path,
              filename: img.path.split('/').last));
        }
        Dio.FormData formData = new Dio.FormData.fromMap({
          "name": name.text,
          "images": arr
        });
        await GalleryServices.create(formData);
    } catch (e) {} finally {
    }
  }
```

GalleryServices class

```
 static Future<bool> create(FormData data) async {
    try {
      Response response =
      await Dio().post(
        "$baseURL/galleries",
        data: data,
      );
      if(response.statusCode==201){
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    } catch(e){
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Demo with source code - https://youtu.be/Zhd4uBEkXBk